# react native geolocation signal strength

Tags: reactjs, react-native, geolocation

How to get signal strength status using react native geolocation? And if its available, how to show this strength status on react-native-camera?

My code is:

```
class GeolocationExample extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            latitude: null,
            longitude: null,
            accuracy: null,
            error: null,
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            (position) => {
                this.setState({
                    latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                    longitude: position.coords.longitude,
                    accuracy: position.coords.accuracy,
                    error: null,
                });
            },
            (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
            { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 5000, maximumAge: 0 },
        );
        //console.log(this.state.latitude);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flexGrow: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                <Text>Latitude: {this.state.latitude}</Text>
                <Text>Longitude: {this.state.longitude}</Text>
                <Text>Accuracy: {this.state.accuracy}</Text>
                {this.state.error ? <Text>Error: {this.state.error}</Text> : null}
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default GeolocationExample;
```